# String getMode() and setMode(String mode), or String mode() and mode(String mode)? Is the way of naming getters/setters changing, and when?

Tags: java, getter, setter

Up until today, I created my objects with getters/setters of the form:

```java
private String mode;
public String getMode() { return this.mode; }
public void setMode(String mode) { this.mode = mode; }
```

But sometimes, API introduced another names for getters/setters:

```java
private String mode;
public String mode() { return this.mode; }
public void mode(String mode) { this.mode = mode; }
```

Especially, since *Java 17*, a `Record` shows its members with getters not having a `get` prefix.

Does the removal of `get`/`set` prefixes to the getters/setters respond to a special need?

Do conception rules exists to choose one form in preference to the other?

Comment: It's just a recommendation, similar to camel-case.  I think it originates from _C++_.